# Routing error UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link_to that takes the users to their profile page. It used to work before but now I keep on getting a uninitialized constant UsersController.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :questions

  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
  get '/users/:id' => 'home#profile'
end
```

Index.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <% if @questions.any? %>
        <% @questions.each do |question| %>
      <div class="well">
          <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-left">
            <% if question.user.avatar.blank? %>
                <img src="http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png" style="width: 75px;">
            <% else %>
                <%= image_tag question.user.avatar, :style => "width:75px;" %>
            <% end %>
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading"><%= link_to question.title, question_path(question), :class => "ques" %></h4>
              <p class="text-right">By <%= link_to question.user.username, question.user, :class => " bg" %></p> <!-- that's what's causing the error -->
              <p class="text-muted"><%= truncate(question.description, :length => 50) %></p>
              <ul class="list-inline navbar-right list-unstyled">
                <li><span style="padding-right: 10px;" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> asked <%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %> ago </span></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <p>No content yet</p>
      <% end %>
```

Rake routes:

```
users_path  GET /users(.:format)    users#index
POST    /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path   GET /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path  GET /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path   GET /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
PUT /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
questions_path  GET /questions(.:format)    questions#index
POST    /questions(.:format)    questions#create
new_question_path   GET /questions/new(.:format)    questions#new
edit_question_path  GET /questions/:id/edit(.:format)   questions#edit
question_path   GET /questions/:id(.:format)    questions#show
PATCH   /questions/:id(.:format)    questions#update
PUT /questions/:id(.:format)    questions#update
DELETE  /questions/:id(.:format)    questions#destroy
new_user_session_path   GET /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new
user_session_path   POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session_path   DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy
user_password_path  POST    /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#create
new_user_password_path  GET /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password_path GET /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
PATCH   /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
PUT /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration_path   GET /users/cancel(.:format) devise/registrations#cancel
user_registration_path  POST    /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration_path  GET /users/sign_up(.:format)    devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration_path GET /users/edit(.:format)   devise/registrations#edit
PATCH   /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
PUT /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
DELETE  /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#destroy
root_path   GET /   home#index
GET /users/:id(.:format)    home#profile
```

As I said before, I don't really know what's causing the error. It was working properly yesterday and I didn't do any changes at all.

Comment: I think it's because you've added `resources :users` which will be looking for a UsersController - worth clarifying though whether you want to use `resources :users` to access users or custom routes like your `get '/users/:id' => 'home#profile'` route.

Comment: Custom routes basically. Idea making the profile view to have the url users/id

Comment: Please post output of 'rake routes'

Comment: @Raymond - Do you have UsersController?

Comment: No I do not have a Users controller and I just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<%= link_to home_profile(question.user.id) %>`.

Assuming **question.user.id** get's user's corresponding id.

Acess users's id in Profile controller by params[:id].

Comment: I updated the rake routes. It's get users/:id home#profile

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting the resources at the bottom instead:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
  get '/users/:id' => 'home#profile'
  resources :users
  resources :questions
end
```

My guess is that it was overriding the `devise_for :users`

Comment: You could also remove `resources :users` completely - they make no sense without `UsersController`